# VTU not reading props object passed to the mount() function

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, vuejs3, vue-test-utils

When mounting a component with props object, VTU does not read props from the options object passed to the mount() function and therefore the test always fails.

**Otp.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="otp-container" ref="otpContainer">
    <input
      data-test="otp-input"
      v-for="(digit, index) in length"
      :key="index"
      type="text"
      maxlength="1"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, defineProps } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  length: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
});
</script>
```

**Otp.spec.js**

```
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Otp from "../../src/components/Otp.vue";

describe("Otp.vue", () => {
  it("should render n otp inputs", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Otp, {
      props: {
        length: 5,
      },
    });

    const otpInputs = wrapper.findAll('[data-test="otp-input"]');
    expect(otpInputs.length).toBe(5);
    //expect(otpInputs).toHaveLength(5);
  });
});
```

I tried using shallowMount and it even says shallowMount is not a function
I expect the length ot otp inputs to be 5 (as it's passed through props)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that only `props` is defined in `<script setup>`, but the template uses `length`, so try either

```
v-for="(digit, index) in props.length"
```

or

```
import { toRef } from 'vue';

const length = toRef(() => props.length);
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting! What I did is that I completely switched to Vite and everything works just fine. From then on I started using Vite in my projects. It's really awesome!